# Failing to querying AWS Athena from Python 2.7, when passing AWS session Token in pyathenajdbc.connect()

Tags: python-2.7, jdbc, credentials, amazon-athena, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to connect to Athena using pyathenajdbc.connect(). I have AWS credentials setup via Multi-factor Authentication. When I don't include the AWS Token in connection string I get following error.

`athena_conn = connect(access_key=AWS_KEY_ID, secret_key=AWS_SECRET, s3_staging_dir='s3://abc-pqr-xyz/processed/athena-outputs/',region_name=REGION)`

`EROR: pyathenajdbc.error.DatabaseError: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: 0d488c0b-1eed-11e7-bad8-711e54af6b73)`

When I include the AWS Token in connection string I get following error -->

`athena_conn = connect(access_key=AWS_KEY_ID, secret_key=AWS_SECRET, token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, s3_staging_dir='s3://abc-pqr-xyz/processed/athena-outputs/',region_name=REGION)`
`ERROR: pyathenajdbc.error.DatabaseError: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: 91751051-1eed-11e7-8347-153dfe3d84a6)`

Does anyone know what is wrong here??

Here is my entire code.

```
from pyathenajdbc import connect
from pyathenajdbc.util import as_pandas
from boto3 import Session
import jpype
jvm_path = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()

_current_credentials = Session().get_credentials()
AWS_KEY_ID = _current_credentials.access_key
AWS_SECRET = _current_credentials.secret_key
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = _current_credentials.token
REGION = "us-east-2"

#athena_conn = connect(access_key=AWS_KEY_ID, secret_key=AWS_SECRET, s3_staging_dir='s3://abc-pqr-xyz/processed/athena-outputs/',region_name=REGION)

athena_conn = connect(access_key=AWS_KEY_ID, secret_key=AWS_SECRET, token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, s3_staging_dir='s3://abc-pqr-xyz/processed/athena-outputs/',region_name=REGION)

cursor = athena_conn.cursor();
query = 'SELECT * FROM xyz.ABC  limit 1;'
cursor.execute(query)
df = as_pandas(cursor)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pyathenajdbc import connect
from pyathenajdbc.util import as_pandas
from boto3 import Session
import os

_current_credentials = Session().get_credentials()

os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = _current_credentials.access_key
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = _current_credentials.secret_key
os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'] = _current_credentials.token


athena_conn = connect(s3_staging_dir='s3://your-bucket/',
           region_name='us-west-2',
           aws_credentials_provider_class='com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.shaded.com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider')

cursor = athena_conn.cursor();
query = 'SELECT * FROM schema.table_name limit 1;'
cursor.execute(query)
df = as_pandas(cursor)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a config file under ~/.aws folder that has the region defined , you could use Session().region_name

The following works just fine (Did not have to import OS):

```
from pyathenajdbc import connect
from pyathenajdbc.util import as_pandas
from boto3 import Session
import jpype
jvm_path = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()

_current_credentials = Session().get_credentials()
AWS_KEY_ID = _current_credentials.access_key
AWS_SECRET = _current_credentials.secret_key
REGION = Session().region_name

athena_conn = connect(access_key=AWS_KEY_ID,
               secret_key=AWS_SECRET,
               s3_staging_dir='path_to_staging_dir',
               region_name=REGION)

cursor = athena_conn.cursor();

query = 'SELECT current_date;'

cursor.execute(query)
df = as_pandas(cursor)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not straightforward but i'm guessing it has something to do with your credentials. You should investigate a bit: try printing your keys and verify if they are valid or not.

Here is an alternative that I use to input my credentials :

```
import configparser    

aws_config_file = '~/.aws/config'

Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
Config.read(os.path.expanduser(aws_config_file))

access_key_id = Config['default']['aws_access_key_id']
secret_key_id = Config['default']['aws_secret_access_key']
```

Otherwise, just to make sure the issue is not related to the jdbc driver, paste the output of the following command

```
import pyathenajdbc 

print(pyathenajdbc.ATHENA_CONNECTION_STRING)
print(pyathenajdbc.ATHENA_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME)
print(pyathenajdbc.ATHENA_DRIVER_DOWNLOAD_URL)
print(pyathenajdbc.ATHENA_JAR)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Here is the output -`jdbc:awsathena://athena.{region}.amazonaws.com:443/hive/{schema}/
com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver
https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar
AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar`

Comment: Also, confirmed that the keys are valid

Comment: I see. I think it has something to do with your permissions on AWS Athena. Please verify if you could access the Athena console using the same credentials

Comment: Hi @Tewfic, Yes I can access the Athena console using those keys. It seems PyAthenaJDBC package that is being used in my code does not support session_token for creating the boto session connection. We may need to modify this to implement missing feature. Or do you know any other package that can be used in this case? Thank you.

Comment: However, it still supports the access_key & secret_key parameters so that's kinda of weird :/ Worst case scenario, you may open an issue here : https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthenaJDBC/issues

Comment: Thank you so much. I will open an issue there and update this tread in case I have a resolution.

Comment: Here is the link to the issue raised with PyAthenaJDBC: [https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthenaJDBC/issues/20]

Comment: @Tewfic, Hi, found the solution it was as simple as setting up environment variable within the python code and passing credentials provider class name in the connection string. See the below answer. Thank you for all your help!!